# Issue with Google Sheets IF formula

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, average, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to create an attendance tracker and need help with a small tweak to a formula.

Right now I'm using the following formula:

```
=IF(sum(G13,H13)=0,"TBD",AVERAGE(G13,H13))
```

Assume there are two cells (Day 1, Day 2)

Certain numbers are entered into the cell depending on if present (1), late(0.5), or absent(0).

Right now the formula is set to put "TBD" if no data is entered into a cell. As soon as a number is entered it will average the two cells together and give a percentage in another cell. The issue I'm having is if someone is absent both days. In that case it will still give a "TBD" in the final cell and I can't figure out how to get it to only give TBD if the cells are empty. If a 0 is put into a cell I want it to average it likes it does for the others.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IF((G13<>"")*(H13<>""), AVERAGE(G13:H13), "TBD")
```

[image: 0]